# buffsize must be integer

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, scp

I'm running into the following error.

*raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer*

I am using python subprocess library to copy a file in directory /home/tito to a remote directory /home/ubuntu/masae_scripts

My code sample is here.

```
import subprocess as sp 
file = '/home/tito/masae_file_2020-11-14.csv'
sp.Popen('scp','-P','2222',file,'hostname@host_ip:/home/ubuntu/masae_scripts')
```

Need help with resolving this

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. As it stands the arguments to SCP must be enclosed in an array.